# How to have access to those properties in this Java object

Tags: java, object

{"Data1": 4,"data2":array of Strings,"Data3":"String","data4": integer}

I have parsed it from a JSONArray to the type Object as the response from the API is a an array of objects , now I need to access the properties values in order to be able to test them and use them in other classes
The code written so far

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL ("www.example.com/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String json = bf.readLine(); 
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println(ja);
        
        for (Object type:ja ) {             
            
            //System.out.println(type);
            Type t = new Type(type);
            
            //System.out.println(t.getName());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you’ve written so far.

Comment: *I have parsed it [...] to type Object* -> `java.lang.Object` doesn't have fields like `Data1`. Create your *own* `class` containing properties like `Data1`, `Data2` etc.

Comment: Yes, I create a new class but I need to populate the new class with the data from the object

Comment: I come from Javascript so excuse me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        URL url = new URL ("www.example.com/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String json = bf.readLine(); 
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println(ja);

        int n=0;
        for (Object type:ja ) {             
            
         
JSONObject object = type.getJSONObject(n++);
String prop=object.getString("propertyname");

        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

try this
```